# Why querying a large number of fields causes memory leak symptoms?

Tags: c#, memory, memory-leaks

I have a question about what is described as "inefficient memory use" in [this](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/visualstudioalm/archive/2013/06/20/using-visual-studio-2013-to-diagnose-net-memory-issues-in-production.aspx) very useful article. The article demonstrates that inefficient memory use can cause dramatic memory growth... and I mean - DRAMATIC.

To answer my question, please take a look at [the article](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/visualstudioalm/archive/2013/06/20/using-visual-studio-2013-to-diagnose-net-memory-issues-in-production.aspx) first.

My question is this: can anybody explain why GC is behaving the way it does as illustrated in the "inefficient memory use" section of the article? Even after triggering GC, memory levels will still be slowly but surely going up.

I've edited the question to place a better focus on my specific query. A good answer will help many developers understand GC better and therefore develop better software.

Many thanks!

Comment: You cannot diagnose specific problems using general descriptions. That you're querying a database and returning more data than needed is a memory issue, sure, but it doesn't mean it creates a memory leak. To figure out **specifically** what you're having problems with you need to use a tool that detects memory leaks and shows them to you.

Comment: Look into using dotTrace Memory Profiles by JetBrains, ANTS Memory Profiler, or any of the other memory profilers out there.

Comment: You should run a memory profiler to see what stuff remains allocated. Or you could show us a minimal verifiable example, so that we can reproduce the issue. Generally, this issue happens when you put stuff into a static place that is never freed, like in-memory session storage.

Comment: Are you getting `OutOfMemoryException`s? No? Its working as expected, that is how a GC is supposed to work.

Comment: Thank you all for your suggestions. We used ANTS memory profiler to determine where the issue was, and we now know what the cause of it is. 
Indeed, with passage of time, we'd be getting an OutOfMemoryException, as memory does not get reclaimed. Even if GC is triggered, not everything is reclaimed, however often you trigger it.

Comment: What I am posting on this forum, however, is a question about explaining GC's behaviour with reference to the article mentioned in my original post. I would appreciate it if somebody could provide an insight into that, please.

Answer (score 0):

> if a "web application is querying a database and bringing back significantly more results than are needed by the application", why is GC not claiming that memory back after all queries are done with, all connections closed, and all related entities cleaned/tidied up?

The first question is, why database is querying and brings back significantly more results that are realy needed? Why not correct this in the first place?

If you put big memory pressure (creating often many temporary data that are later to be release), GC in fact will be cleaning it but because of so many data is created, it will be slow and very inefficent.

Comment: Konrad, thanks for your answer. 
Please note that the question is about the example sited in the article I am referring to above, and is intended to help clarify the inner workings of garbage collection. This post is not seeking any advice on how to handle the specific problem we had - all the advice we needed was in the above-mentioned article.